# Still receiving null error even after I set the function to only run if truthy?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am still receiving this error:

```
Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

even after I put my code within an if(truthy){...} statement?

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(response) {
    console.log(response);
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = response;
  }
})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The error means that your `getElementById()` call is returning `null`, meaning that there's no element with that id in the document.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I am aware of what the error means, but am stumped as to why it isn't solved by placing a if(truthy){...} statement where the code should be getting called.. The element eventually returns a real value but I am trying to bypass the error.

Comment: Your `if` statement checks the value of `response`, which is apparently independent of the state of affairs with respect to that element being in the DOM.  Your code does *not* check whether `getElementById()` returns non-null.

Comment: ah, I think I understand what you mean. Thank you for pointing that out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the if statement should have contained.

```
if(document.getElementById('count') !== null) {..}
```